# What is the correct template for a "working paper" in Bib?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In economics, we often need to cite working paper not published yet.

I am just wondering if we should use `@unpublished`or `@report`?

This is example I am writing in my `bib` file. Is it OK?

```
@unpublished{ChernozhukovFernandez-ValKowalski2014,
    author  = "Victor Chernozhukov and Iv{\'a}n Fern{\'a}ndez-Val and Amanda Kowalski",
    title   = "QUANTILE REGRESSION WITH CENSORING AND ENDOGENEITY",
    year    = "2014",
    note    = "Working paper",
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, since `@report` is not a recognized entry type in most bibliography styles, I wouldn't use it. Use `@techreport` instead.

The answer to your question depends crucially on *how* the paper is being circulated. If it's part of a working paper series or discussion paper series, it probably has some kind of information on the title page that identifies it as, say, a "National Bureau of Economic Research Working Paper" along with a number. If so, you should enter its information using the `@techreport` entry type. If it does not, you're better off using the `@unpublished` entry type.

For the paper you mention, Amanda Kowalski's website notes that it was circulated in 2011 (not 2014) both as an NBER working paper and as a Cowles Foundation discussion paper. To reference the 2011 working paper version, I'd therefore use the `@techreport` entry type. Incidentally, the paper is also listed as "forthcoming" in the Journal of Econometrics; you might therefore choose the `@article` type and list its year as "forthcoming".