# Show series field when citing report

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

The exact opposite of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128928/31839), I'd like to show the "Series" field when citing working papers, which I currently do using item type "Report".

(I use report because Zotero doesn't have the `techreport` field, which [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223828/31839) suggests using.)

The resulting citation looks fine, but I need to show [the working paper series](http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/162611468739486410/Military-expenditure-threats-aid-and-arms-races) it belongs to.

How can I add this field to my bibliography?

## foo.bib

```
@report{collier_military_2002,
  location = {{Washington D.C}},
  title = {Military {{Expenditure}}: {{Threats}}, {{Aid}} and {{Arms Races}}},
  number = {WPS2927},
  series = {Policy, Research Working Paper},
  institution = {{World Bank}},
  date = {2002},
  author = {Collier, Paul and Hoeffler, Anke}
}
```

## foo.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}    
\addbibresource{foo.bib}    
\begin{document}    
I love to cite \textcite{collier_military_2002}.    
\printbibliography    
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: There's no working paper series name!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@report`s don't support the `series` field. Instead they have a `type`. I think in this case `type`+`number` is more appropriate than `series`+`number`. Incidentally, even http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/162611468739486410/ lists "Policy Research Working Paper" as "doument type".

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{collier_military_2002,
  location    = {Washington, DC},
  title       = {Military Expenditure: Threats, Aid and Arms Races},
  number      = {WPS2927},
  type        = {Policy Research Working Paper},
  institution = {World Bank},
  date        = {2002-11},
  author      = {Collier, Paul and Hoeffler, Anke}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{collier_military_2002}.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]